# Looping through an array and exiting when the right value is matched?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

In short, is there a way to exit the loop if my condition is met in a functional way?

Let me elaborate.
Let's say I have an array:-

```
var arr = [4,6,2,24,16,13,88,64,28,39,66,26,9]
```

and I want to extract the first odd number from `arr`.
My initial thought was that I could just use `.some` and get the first element whenever my condition is met but when I went over MDN I quickly found out that it's not as simple as I thought it would be cause `.some` only returns `boolean` value.
So, my another approach was to use `.filter` which would filter out all the odd numbers and grab the first one but doing this will make the loop go through the entire array even though `filter` has already found the first odd number in the loop. This is okay for small arrays but for arrays with huge elements, it feels that this is quite unnecessary.

Am I missing something with functional technique or is this usually how functional programming goes?

Just for the reference my solution with `.some` and `.filter` are:-

```
var result1, result2;

//Loop ends on the right element but result wrong value
var arr = [4, 6, 2, 24, 16, 13, 88, 64, 28, 39, 66, 26, 9];
result1 = arr.some(function (i) {
    return i % 2;
});

//Has right value but loop continues till the end
result2 = arr.filter(function (i) {
    return i % 2;
})[0];
```

Comment: Why not just use a good ol fashion *for-loop* and *break* from it when you met your requirement?

Comment: You could use array.prototype.find - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find - with the polyfill for stupid browsers

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I don't think using `for-loop` is functional way of to do it. 
@JaromandaX. OMG, yes!! That's probably what I'm missing. Thanks a bunch. Can you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) - included on that page is a polyfill for stupid browsers

usage:

```
result1 = arr.find(function(i){
  return i%2;
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. What's great about this is that I can just pass around `arr.find` to any parameter without fiddling around with side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a variable to store the first odd value.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6kgb3o7t/)

```js
var arr = [4, 6, 2, 24, 16, 13, 88, 64, 28, 39, 66, 26, 9];
var odd = 0;
arr.some(function(i) {
  console.log(i); // To check if this loop over all the elements of array

  odd = i; // Assign the value
  return i % 2;
});

document.write(odd);
```

Comment: This is good but the anonymous function has a side-effect to it which sort of defeats the purpose of being functional. I suppose I can wrap that into another function and return the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `while` loop

```js
var arr = [4, 6, 2, 24, 16, 13, 88, 64, 28, 39, 66, 26, 9];
var i = 0;
// should break if odd number found, 
// `i` would be index of first odd number found in `arr`
while (arr[i] % 2 === 0 && i < arr.length) {
  ++i;
};
console.log(arr[i])
```